# How to create collasped side menu bar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to add a side menu bar in my react application . Initially it should be closed only icons
should be visible and on clicking on one icon entire sidemenu should menu..I am doing this way
But it is not closing and is not closing.. I tried out different ways but not able to achieve it

Comment: You'd have to show us your function for opening and closing the menu as well.

Comment: @Kokodoko I am trying using css...I don;t know how to do it with  function

Comment: @Karan you can't do it with CSS, because you can't handle mouse clicks from CSS. Show us the place of use SideMenu, the code of parent element.

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov there is not parent , I want to show this side menu on left hand side

Comment: @Karan yes, but anyway it must has a parent, even if it is App. Just show the place where you put <SideMenu />

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov  there is nothing only <div><SideMenu/></div>

Comment: @Karan yes, I told about it. Show the full code of this component, where you have <div><SideMenu/></div>

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov check now I Have mention where I have added the sidemenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In parent component:

```
const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false)

return <div>{show ? <SideMenu /> : <Icon />}</div>
```

If I understood an issue properly.

And use onClick in Icon to change show state.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy how can I show Initial Icons

Comment: It's up to you. You can use icons from any UI kit (like material icons)